# Corner Radius Working on Obj-C but not in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, calayer

I'm using this code on Obj-C and it does works:

```
CALayer *btnLayer = [self.priceLabel layer];
[btnLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
[btnLayer setCornerRadius:5.0f];
```

It does makes rounded corners on my button CALayer.

But is not working on swift:

```
var btnLayer:CALayer! = self.priceLabel.layer
[btnLayer.masksToBounds:true]
[btnLayer.cornerRadius = 5.0]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code you wrote might be valid swift, but it does not do what you think it does.

Put it in a Xcode playground and see for yourself.

[image]

As you can see in the sidebar you have created a dictionary and something else that roughly looks like an empty array. Not quite what you want.

Try this instead:

```
btnLayer.masksToBounds = true
btnLayer.cornerRadius = 5.0
```

You might want to read the [Swift Programming Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/) again.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't knew I was creating an empty array over there. Your code fixed my problem, thanks mate!